# How does Radiant Scrollwielder 2nd ability work with adventure spells?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

[Radiant Scrollwielder](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Radiant%20Scrollwielder) reads:

> At the beginning of your upkeep, exile an instant or sorcery card at random from your graveyard. You may cast it this turn. If a spell cast this way would be put into your graveyard, exile it instead.

Say I have a [Bonecrusher Giant](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Bonecrusher%20Giant) in my graveyard, will Scrollwielder attempt to exile the "Stomp" part of the card, and if i then cast it will I then put Bonecrusher Giant in the adventure zone?